# How to wait for an object to be asynchronously edited?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have an `array` of `items` where I want to append an async value `getProductMinQuantity`.

The problem is that the render `res.status(200)...` is sent before item.order_quantity_minimum  had been edited.

I thought that a map like below would create a new promise with the items updated.

`newResult` is a type `Promise<any>[] | undefined`, I cannot do `.then` `.catch` to then execut my `res.status` in it.

```
const getCart = async () => {
  
  ...

  let newResult = result.data?.line_items.physical_items.map(async (item: any) =>
    item.order_quantity_minimum = await getProductMinQuantity(item.product_id)
  )

  res.status(200).json({
    data: result.data ? normalizeCart(result.data) : null,
  })
}
```

Any thought how I can arrange that ?

Comment: But why build a `newResult` array if you don't use it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic question; you can't use `await` inside a synchronous array method (map, forEach, filter etc.). Instead, use a `for...of` loop.

```
let newResult = []

for(let item of result.data?.line_items.physical_items) {
  item.order_quantity_minimum = await getProductMinQuantity(item.product_id)
  newResult.push(item);
}

// Do something with newResult
```

Comment: It is telling me that  result.data?.line_items.physical_items could have a value 'undefined'

Comment: Indeed, well, add `if(result.data?.line_items.physical_items)`

Comment: Thanks I even don't need the `newResult` with `for...of`, my result.data?.line_items.physical_items is nicely edited before to send my response.

Comment: Yeah, hence my comment above asking why you are building a `newResult` array and not using it afterwards. Indeed, every `item` is modified by reference directly in `physical_items`

Comment: In the previous way I used it, as said I tried to read and to do stuff with it but without success. I did not write all what I tried because I knew the way I was doing was wrong. But did not know about `for...of`. I guess I will use more `for...of` now :)